# Microsoft Graph API read mail status code 404 not found error despite despite consented permissions

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

When using the Microsoft Graph API endpoint `/v1.0/me/messages`, I'm presented with a 404 error despite consented with Mail.Read permission.

```
{'error': {'code': 'ResourceNotFound',
  'message': 'Resource could not be discovered.',
  'innerError': {'date': '2021-06-02T13:25:37',
   'request-id': '8e12f76c-dc76-407e-8d74-71cb319f7637',
   'client-request-id': '8e12f76c-dc76-407e-8d74-71cb319f7637'}}}
```

I've granted Mail.Read permission in Azure portal.

I've tried the same Graph Explorer, and it works fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCVV2.png)
Any suggestions on how to get a 200 OK instead?

**EDIT 1**:
Currently, my access token allows me to get my profile through endpoint `/me`. However, if I try to use `/me/mailFolders` or `/me/messages` to get my mails I get the error above.

Comment: How are you getting the token?

Comment: Use MSAL python library, initiate a ```PublicClientApplication``` class with my registered application id and ```https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_tenant}```, then call the ```acquire_token_interactive``` method with scope = ```'User.Read', 'Mail.Read', 'MailboxSettings.Read'``` to get the token interacively.

Comment: Which account are you using?

Comment: my personal microsoft account which is in the same Azure active directory as the registered application. The supported account type of my application is ```Accounts in this directory```

Comment: Use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` which allows both personal and work accounts to login

Comment: Yes. But with my original settings, I can log with my personal account and get the token, with which I can use ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me``` to get my profile. The problem is I can't use endpoints like ```/me/mailFolders``` or ```/me/messages```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the URL which is suggested above? Try it once and see if you are able to get your personal mailbox mails or not. I am asking you to do this because if you are able to get results in Graph Explorer then its not an issue with Graph API but the issue with the code you written.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to do that because it requires me to change the signInAudience of my Azure application to ```AzureADMultipleOrgs```, which prevents me from signing in with my personal account. I tried to change it to ```AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount```  by editing the manifest but it failed with error ```Property accessTokenAcceptedVersion is invalid```.